# How to Reset File Number on the Fuji X-T10?

Tags: filenames, fujifilm-xt10

It is usually obvious but with the Fuji X-T10, I have not found how yet. The file counter is already in the high thousands and I'd rather avoid numbers wrapping around (although I expect it to happen in two different folders).

How can I reset the counter so that the next image taken with the Fuji X-T10 is DSCF0001.JPG/RAF ?

*Formatting and changing cards does not do the trick.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change the SETUP > SAVE DATA SET-UP > FRAME NO. menu setting from CONTINUOUS to RENEW. If it's set to RENEW, then the numbering will reset to 0001 when you format the card or use a new one.

See: http://fujifilm-dsc.com/en/manual/x-t10/menu_setup/save_data_set-up/index.html

Comment: Now I found it. Thank you! There is one more level of indirection called 'SAVED DATA SET-UP' which is why I could not find it and I've added it to your answer.

Comment: @Itai Ah. I was going by the menus on my X100T over the manual. D'oh! Thanks for the edit!